# Get dynamic value with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get this number (-22.65) that changes in the website
[Page code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMMQR.png)

I have tried with the xpath, with contain text...

```
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'valueValue-2KhwsEwE')]").text
print(text)
```

But in any case I get the number itself... I get the following message:

> File "C:\Users\ESJOMAN2.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 22, in 
> text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'valueValue-2KhwsEwE')]").text
>
> File "C:\Users\ESJOMAN2\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
> return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
>
> File "C:\Users\ESJOMAN2\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
> return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
>
> File "C:\Users\ESJOMAN2\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
> self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>
> File "C:\Users\ESJOMAN2\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>
> NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(text(),'valueValue-2KhwsEwE')]"}
> (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.90)

Any ideas?

Comment: Changes how? In relation to the page. Also the -2KhwsEwE seems to be dynamic just remove it.

Comment: it can't find the element with that locator. Perhaps try a wait.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
try:
    text = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, 'ELEMENT XPATH'))
    )
except:
    driver.quit()

print(text.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like that:

```
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'sourcesWrapper')]//div[contains(),'valueValue']").text
```

or

```
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'sourcesWrapper')]//div[contains(),'valueValue']").get_attribute('value')
```

before that, use

```
time.sleep(5)
```

so code snipped looks like:

```
time.sleep(5)
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'sourcesWrapper')]//div[contains(),'valueValue']").text
print(text)
```

By the way, have you checked, might your elements inside iframe, did iframe locate on your page?